# composition of t-structures "par recollement"

Tags: triangulated-categories

It is a classical result in Beilinson-Bernstein-Deligne's "Faisceaux Pervers" (thm. 1.4.9) that given three triangulated categories $\mathbf{D}_0, \mathbf{D}_1, \mathbf{D}_{01}$ and a [recollement](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/recollement) between them, arranged as
$$
\mathbf{D}_0 \begin{smallmatrix}  \overset{i_L}{\leftarrow} \\ \to \\ \underset{i_R}\leftarrow \end{smallmatrix}
\mathbf{D}_{01} \begin{smallmatrix} \overset{q_L}\leftarrow \\ \to \\ \underset{q_R}\leftarrow \end{smallmatrix} \mathbf{D}_1
$$
a pair of $t$-structures $\mathfrak t_i = (\mathbf{D}_i^\ge, \mathbf{D}_i^\le)$ on $\mathbf{D}_i$ can be lifted to a $t$-structure $\mathfrak t:=\mathfrak t_0 \underset{(i,q)}\boxtimes \mathfrak t_1 = (\mathbf{D}_{01}^\ge ,\mathbf{D}_{01}^\le )$: the two classes of $\mathfrak t$ are
$$
\mathbf{D}_{01}^\ge = \{ X\mid qX \in \mathbf{D}_1^\ge,\; i_L X \in \mathbf{D}_0^\ge \}
$$
$$
\mathbf{D}_{01}^\le = \{ Y\mid qY\in \mathbf{D}_1^\le , \; i_RY\in \mathbf{D}_0^\le\}
$$
Now, my question is:

> is the operation $\boxtimes$ associative in any sensible way?

I do not expect it to be, in full generality: if you try to verify it, at a certain point you need a certain square of adjoints to be commutative. But in the geometric main example of a space stratified by closed subspaces (and even in more algebraic examples where the recollements are obtained "functorially" from an initial set of data) this seems to be true.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a semiorthogonal decomposition with three components and a t-structure on each of them, and now you want to glue them in two different ways?

Comment: Yes, I think I'm in that situation.